# brake wear (front vs. rear)

Tags: brakes

I have been monitoring the service indicator in my E90 and have been noticing that the service countdown for my rear brakes has been decreasing fairly rapidly whereas the front brakes countdown has actually been increasing. When I first picked up the car (new) they both indicated about 45,000 km until the next service. Now, 2 months and 4,200 later, the front brake indicator is showing 47,000 km until next service and the rear indicator is showing 40,000 km.

Any ideas as to why the rears would wear out faster? Also, does the indicator monitor actual brake life or only an estimate based on driving style, conditions, etc?

I use the parking brake every time I put the car in park. I figured that it would be easier on the transmission this way. Should I only do it when the car is on an incline? 
Any thoughts, advice would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: the numbers are as you guess based on some formula. I believe the bmw has an actual sensor to detect about half life remaining, but before that it is strictly an estimate.

Answer (score 1):

My 335i had to get the rear brake pads replaced at about 10.5k miles. Now I'm at just under 14k miles and had a service appointment and the brakes all look fine. The CBS still indicate that the rear brakes will have to be replaced in less miles than the still original front brake pads. It's definitely because of the DSC and no LSD trying to control the high amount of torque going to the rear wheels. You can't just shut off the DSC completely though, because it's not pretty when the car loses all control and spins out all over the place on high boost corners.